# SOLR - remove all other results if exact match is found

Tags: solr, match

I'm using EgdeNGramFilterFactory to match product EAN codes.

Is there any possibility to remove all other results if an exact existing EAN is found? Solr always displays the most relevant EAN first, by I would like to only show that one if possible.

I have read a lot of answers on stackoverflow, but all of them mentioned boost, which is not an issue in my case. Results scores are OK, in my case, it's a matter of **COMPLETELY REMOVING** all other results, if an exact match is found.

**Current behavior:**

EAN list: 12345, 12347, 12389

search: 123, results: 12345, 12347, 12389

search: 12345, results: 12345, 12347, 12389

**Wanted behavior:**

search: 123, results: 12345, 12347, 12389

search: 12345, results: 12345

```
<field name="ean" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="SuggestEan" type="text_suggest_edge_ngram_single" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<copyField source="ean" dest="SuggestEan" maxChars="30000"/>

<fieldType name="text_suggest_edge_ngram_single" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\W+" replacement=""/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="30" minGramSize="3"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**QF:** ean^10 SuggestEan^8

Comment: Any reason why you can't handle it in your controller that calls Solr? Since it's an exact match, making the comparison and not show any more entries should be at most a couple of lines of code.

Comment: I'd like to get the most out of Solr configuration so I won't have to further process the results. But so far, this seems indeed the only solution. Thank you.

Comment: You can also make two queries - since the exact match is against a field which would only return a single document, it should be very quick under any condition.

Comment: MatsLindh please add this as an answer so I can close the question. It's the best approach indeed since the exact match query is super-fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either handle it in your controller that makes the Solr call (a direct comparison for an exact match shouldn't require much more than a `==` and a if-clause), or do two queries - one to retrieve exact matches and one to do a regular search.

If the first search gets a hit (which is a direct match and will be a quick index lookup under most conditions), don't do the second query.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom post-filter or a custom search component. But it is probably easiest to do it in the Solr client, as MatsLindh suggested.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow MatsLindth advice. Writing JAVA components would be an overkill for me right now, since I program mainly on PHP :)